# PHP file is downloaded, not loaded

Tags: php, html

I have the following php file:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

echo "test";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

My httpd.conf file has the following entry:

```
grep php /var/apache/conf/httpd.conf
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
```

Why would the file always be downloaded and not loaded in the browser?

Comment: Did you restart Apache since you had made that addition?

Comment: Make sure to restart apache and try updating the permissions.

Comment: I didn't make the change to the config file, that has been in place for years.

Comment: php may be loaded, but has apache been told to treat `.php` files as php scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set the correct content handler / MIME-type for .php files. The default Ubuntu php configuration contains:-

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    # To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
    # (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
    # prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            php_admin_value engine Off
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I selected this answer as this was additional data I did not know about the config, however it did not resolve the problem.  Turns out the sys. admins have a setting somewhere that only allows php scripts to be run out of a certain folder after review.